# Trying to get property of a non-object

Tags: php

I thought I had resolved this error when I added the if block below, but I'm still erroring out. This line of code is causing the following errror:

Fatal PHP error on line 95 of /XXXXX/GetContactValuesOsVc.php:
Trying to get property of non-object

Line 95 is the if condition here:

```
if($contact->CustomFields->c->ask_again->LookupName){
    $Contactname=$contact->CustomFields->c->ask_again->LookupName;
}
```

Anyone know why merely checking for existence (what that line should be doing I think) would be causing the error im getting?

Comment: PHP is not JavaScript. Use the `isset` command: `if(isset($contact->CustomFields->c->ask_gain->LookupName)){...`

Comment: Wow...that was a...really boneheaded move. Thanks!